# Update server name connection access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Having issues finding something that should be easy.

Anyways currently our access database has linked table to a different server. I need to upgrade to new server name and database name. I tried and works great for me.

The end user tested and says the ODBC connection i setup has failed. Not sure why its doing this.

any help would be great.

Comment: Was a new DSN with a new name set up on your PC for the new server and new linked tables? Was the same done on the user's PC?

Answer (score 2):

Access by default uses DSN-less connections.

So you need to launch the linked table manager. If you follow the default prompts for creating a DSN, (that is a FILE dsn), then when Access links the tables, they are converted to DSN-less links.

This means:
You don’t need to run some VBA code on start-up.

You don’t need to create DSN less connections, since Access by default creates and uses DSN links.

You don’t have to setup a DSN on each computer.

So simply launch the linked table manager. Get the links working on your computer. Once you are sure the links are working, then usually the next step is to create the compiled accDE.

After above, and the optional compile to accDE (if that’s what you been using all along), then you can simply distribute the new front end to each work station, and all should be well.

You “can” choose to setup some VBA code to re-link, but it not required.

Edit:
ALL that is required here is to click the mouse, and type in a name for the FILE dsn.
Remember, access does NOT need this AFTER you link.
Remember access WILL create  DSN-less connection for you.
Remember, you do NOT need to copy or setup the DSN on the target computer.

The steps are:

click on the ODBC button - ribbon - external data tab

[image]

We want to link to sql server, NOT import, so:

[image]

Now this can trip up users, because OFTEN windows 10, the following folder is LOCKED down - you don't have admin rights, so click on new, don't use this default folder UNLESS you launched access as a "admin", and you likely did not. So hit new:

[image]

Now select your SQL driver. I use the legacy "sql driver". If you used newer and later data types, then you want to choose the "native 11" or later driver. However this driver is NOT installed on each workstation by default - but the sql one is.

[image]

So browse to my documents, type in a name and whack save
eg this:

[image]

You now back to this dialog:

[image]

We are NOW ready to start entering information for the connection:

Hit finish:

[image]

Now for description - we DO NOT care!!!

However, for the server name, you must enter

SERVERNAME\NAME OF SQL INSTANCE.

If you running SQL express local, then localhost is fine for server name, and the DEFAULT for sql server is SQLEXPRESS. You REALLY do need the name of the sql instance and ALSO the server name (in my example, localhost is the name, but could be server01\SQLEXPRESS or whatever)

[image]

enter you logon name + password.
If you are using "windows authentication", then no logon is required.

[image]

MAKE SURE you select/set the correct database. If the box is greay out then you ONLY have rights to the defaulted choice that you will not be able to change.

[image]

Now hit next

[image]

Now select your tables. DO NOT forget to click/check the SAVE password option

[image]

So that is the screen caps.
The result is a DSN-LESS connection.

=========
Edit2:
For EXISTING tables, and pointing them to a new server?

You simply launch the linked table manager:
[image]

Now MAKE SURE you select the prompt for new location.
(this option forces + allows  you to choose NEW or
different server to link EXISTING tables to.

[image]

At this point in time, you NOW follow the
exact SAME steps as above to create a new
link, but this will let you link + point
to a different server for existing linked
tables.

Comment: Its being a pain allowing me save a DSN as a file. I can save a OBDC connection just file(see link) however the method you spoke of its being a pain. Help please?   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1076359

Comment: Creating a FILE dsn is the default prompts. Often on windows 10, the "default" location for file dsn's is read only, so just hit "new" on the first "select data sources" dialog. Select "sql server"., on the next dialog, hit browse and use say "my documents" (since default loc is read only on windows 10). browse to my docs, and type in any name you want, and then hit save. Now you can start the "next" button dialogs to create the DSN. As I stated, access will NOT require NOR use that DSN. It is ONLY used one time during re-link. As a result you do NOT need to write VBA code etc.

Comment: Also, why in that screen cap are you creating a "user" DSN? I said to JUST use the defaults offered to you. If you create a FILE dsn (the default prompt), then you don't need any code or anything after you link.

Comment: I have added a series of screen shots to show the steps. How this works is the same for any server linking of tables. So note the new screen caps and edits I added to my answer.

Comment: I have ALSO added the steps to re-link and point existing tables to a new server. As noted, once you do this, then no VBA code or re-linking is required if you deploy the application to other users on your network.

Comment: Albert Kallal thank you so much for your time. This is so hopeful!! Just one more thing getting this....

Comment: Albert Kallal thank you so much for your time. This is so hopeful!! Just one more thing getting this.... Run time error 3151 ODBC connection to New97 Failed DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC", "ODBC;DSN=New97;UID=tcm;TABLE=bc_SESSIONS", acTable, "bc_SESSIONS", "PUBLIC_bc_SESSIONS1"

Comment: That transferDatabase has the connection string right in the code. I would change the code to work with a linked table. (start a new question). Or what you do is link your tables, and then "grab" the connection string from a existing linked table.

Answer (score 1):

The connection might fail on the end user's PCs if they don't have an ODBC Data Source Name (DSN) set up on their PCs like you do.

To overcome this requirement, I usually use some code like this in a standard module

```
Const MY_CONNECTION As String = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=TheServerName;DATABASE=TheDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

Public Sub ReConnect()

    Dim tdf As TableDef ' for linked tables
    Dim qdf As QueryDef ' for pass through queries

    With CurrentDb
        For Each tdf In .TableDefs
            With tdf
                If (.Attributes And dbAttachedODBC) = dbAttachedODBC Then
                    .Connect = MY_CONNECTION
                    .RefreshLink
                End If
            End With
        Next
        For Each qdf In .QueryDefs
            With qdf
                If .Type = dbQSQLPassThrough Or .Type = dbQSPTBulk Then
                    .Connect = MY_CONNECTION
                End If
                .Close
            End With
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

I run this procedure manually before distributing the Access frontend.

Comment: Can I just put this under form_load()

Comment: Yes, you can, but if you run it once before distributing your Access file, there should be no need to repeatedly run it on the end user's versions.

Comment: see my answer below. You don't need VBA re-link code if you not been using such code in the past. This is a "optional" suggestion. You can use the linked table manager, and it creates DSN-less links for you. After a re-link it is simple matter to re-distribute your front end to each work station. You do NOT need to setup nor create DSN's on each workstation if you created and used the default FILE dsn on your development workstation with the linked table manager. Access converts the links to DSN less for you automatic when using the linked table manager with a file dsn.

Comment: Thank you Albert, this was really new to me. I always thought that I would have to distribute the connection file together with the database file, therefore I created Computer DSNs all the time (like obviously the OP). :-)